# java display contents of a folder

Tags: java

I have a JAVA program to display the contents of a folder: files, folders and the contents of the subfolders.

```
public static void displayContent(File curFolder, int indent){

    if(curDir.isFile()){
        System.out.println(curDir.getName());
    } else if(curDir.isFolder()){
        System.out.println(curDir.getName());
        if(curDir.length() > 0){
            for(File file: curDir.listFiles()){
                displayContent(file, indent + 4);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I created a test folder with a bunch of subfolders to test my program and it runs very well. But when I use my program to test system folders such as `"C:\Users"`, it returns a lot of unexpected results:

1. It displays some folders I cannot find in the folder, such as "All users", "Application Data". Plus they are not hidden files.
2. Some folders and files do exist, but they do not show in my results. The name of the folder containing these files begins with a dot, such as ".android". What is this type of folder? How do I deal with it?

*My OS is windows 8; IDE is NetBeans 8.0.*

Comment: Can you post the loop?

Comment: The method displayContent(File curFolder, int indent) is recursive.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you want to print the path instead of printing the name. That way you can see the folder structure. Also, your code seems to have a fairly large number of typos,

```
public static void displayContent(File curDir, int indent) { // <-- curDir used below
  if (curDir.isFile()) {
    System.out.println(curDir.getPath());
  } else if (curDir.isDirectory()) {
    System.out.println(curDir.getPath());
    for (File file : curDir.listFiles()) {
      displayContent(file, indent + 4); // <-- displayContent not displayContents.
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for correcting my typo. Path may work better. But how to find the folders in the results but do not exist?

Comment: The folders in the result do exist, you just don't know which folder it is... because your code doesn't really give you enough information. Make sure you look with the command prompt, or configure explorer to show hidden files and folders.